# Bug while trying to find sum of primes with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, primes

I am trying to get the sum of an array of prime numbers, and I understand there are more elegant ways to do that and have seen the links to those solutions.

My problem is something that's wrong within this specific script, and I'm trying to understand what's causing THIS code to fail.

The issue is that the numbers 9, 15 and many others are being being added into the primes array, even though they all, correctly, fail a test to check if they're prime numbers. I can't wrap my head around what in the script is causing the numbers to push to the array despite failing that test. Again, I'm not looking for a completely different/better approach to summing the primes, but some help in identifying what exactly is wrong in this script would be really appreciated.

```js
function totalPrime(num) {
  var nums = [];
  var primes = [];

  for (var i = 1;
    (num - i) > 1; i++) {
    nums.push(num - i);
  }

  nums.forEach(isPrime);

  function isPrime(n) {
    var a = [];
    var test;
    if (n === 1) {} else if (n === 2) {
      primes.push(n);
    } else {
      for (var i = 1;
        (n - i) > 1; i++) {
        a.push(n - i);
      }
      a.forEach(function(x) {
        if ((n % x) === 0) {
          test = false;
        } else {
          test = true;
        }
      });
      if (test) {
        primes.push(n);
      } else {}
    };
  }

  console.log(primes.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }));
}

totalPrime(5);
```

Same script with logging I was using to debug:

```js
function totalPrime(num) {
  var nums = [];
  var primes = [];

  for (var i = 1;
    (num - i) > 1; i++) {
    nums.push(num - i);
  }

  nums.forEach(isPrime);


  function isPrime(n) {
    var a = [];
    var test;
    if (n === 1) {
      console.log(n + ' is NOT a prime number');
    } else if (n === 2) {
      console.log(n + ' IS a prime number');
      primes.push(n);
    } else {
      for (var i = 1;
        (n - i) > 1; i++) {
        a.push(n - i);
      }
      a.forEach(function(x) {
        if ((n % x) === 0) {
          test = false;
          console.log(n + ' % ' + x + ' equals 0');
          console.log(x + ' fails check');
        } else {
          test = true;
          console.log(n + ' % ' + x + ' does NOT equal 0');
          console.log(x + ' passes check');
        }
      });
      if (test) {
        console.log(n + ' IS a prime number.');
        primes.push(n);
      } else {
        console.log(n + ' is NOT a prime number.');
      }
    };
  }

  console.log(primes);
  console.log(primes.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }));
}

totalPrime(5);
```

Comment: setting the `test` variable inside the `a.forEach(function(x) {` ensures that its final value after that call will be the value that was set on its *last* iteration.

Comment: I think what you meant to do was to initialize `test = true` *before* the `.forEach`, and then set it only to `false` inside the callback.

Comment: Adding to what @CrazyTrain is saying, you are setting it to false at 9 % 3 but turning around at 9 % 2 and setting test to true. You would be better off, in my opinion, using a for loop and breaking the loop as soon as you find a false. This will not only get the job done but when you go through larger numbers it will stop you from having to go through all iterations when at iteration 2 you realize it's false.

Comment: It is difficult to read the code if you use magic names like `n` `x` `a` for variables.  Also please read the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)  for efficient way of checking if number is prime. I would recommend to use DEBUG in any browser to see what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test` value in each test override the previous check. Thus, actualy only the last check (divide in 2) become relevant, and all the odd primes fail.

You can correct it by change the default of `test` to `true`, and remove the exist line in the code `test = true;`.

The corrected code:

```
function isPrime(n) {
  var a = [];
  var test = true;
  if (n === 1) {} else if (n === 2) {
    primes.push(n);
  } else {
    for (var i = 1;
      (n - i) > 1; i++) {
      a.push(n - i);
    }
    a.forEach(function(x) {
      if ((n % x) === 0) {
        test = false;
      } 
    });
    if (test) {
      primes.push(n);
    }
  };
}
```